# Webconfig entries are added on each deployment

Tags: 2010, web-config

I have an issue, basically everytime I deploy a solution it adds 3 entries of safecontrols which basically do not exist in my project anymore. Before they were there, but not anymore.

Each time after solution deployment, I can see them on 2 web application config files, althought I deploy wsp only to one solution.

In the logs I see the following:

> Updating SPPersistedObject SPWebConfigFileChanges
>   Name=WebConfigChanges .... WebConfigModification: Adding web config
>   node - Path - configuration/SharePoint/SafeControls Node name -
>   SafeControl...

I'm thinking maybe those changes are saved somewhere and every time I deploy it automatically adds those entries to all web application config file?

I did clean a cache already and did a restart of the machine etc etc, but still no solution

Comment: did you completely removed the old solutions, from GAC as well? check if dll exist in GAC fodler?

Comment: But when i retract is it automatically not retracted?

Comment: And no after retracting in the assembly i don't see any of the entries remaining which would mention my solution :/

Comment: ok fine, some time it stays their...try to recyle the timer services & admin service on all servers?

Comment: recycle? you mean restart sharepoint timer and sharepoint admin service?

Comment: it is strange that also when i retract the solution, it adds again those entries :/